# How to get an object item from package.json in Vue / Quasar

Tags: vue.js, components, package.json, quasar-framework

I am trying to get the 'version' from package.json in my Vue/Quasar project.

There was an information in the internet to use this code:

```
import { version } from '../package.json'
```

Now I am a beginner and I cannot get this running.
My current code looks somewhat like this:

```
<template>
  // ... REMOVED CODE FOR BETTER READABILITY

  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <q-page-container>
      <div>VERSION: {{ version }}</div>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import { version } from '../package.json'
export default {
  name: 'Layout',

  data () {
    return {
      leftDrawerOpen: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    version
  }
}
</script>
```

ESLint throws the following error:

> 87:5  error  The "version" component has been registered but not used
>   vue/no-unused-components

How do I use the component variable I imported correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this piece of code:

```
components: {
    version
}
```

You are trying to register it as a component which it is not.

Then add the version to vue:

```
data () {
   ...
   version: version
}
```

Comment: this only changes the error message slightly: `77:10  error  'version' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars`

Comment: I have updated my answer, try adding the version you have imported to Vue's `data ()...`: `version: version`

Comment: Would I add this into the return {} just after the declaration of leftDrawerOpen? Because this gives me a compile error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Comment: Yes -`just after the declaration of leftDrawerOpen? `.

Make sure the path (the folder level) '../package.json' is correct. Which folder are you in? Try '../../package.json' or '../../../package.json'  ...

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps it will works fine

1. import {version} from '../../package.json'
2. data: () => ({
   appVersion:version
   }),
3. {{appVersion}}

(or)

Vue.prototype.application_version = require('../package.json').version;

Comment: Could you provide a full code answer, not just very small parts provided as steps.